# Mariadb: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mariadb

In my application, I have an issue where I receive the "MySQL server has gone away" error during a quite long-running transaction. I know this has already been asked a lot, but I tried my test to go through all possible causes.

The one thing that baffles me a lot, is this error message in the log of the MariaDB server:

> [Warning] Aborted connection 6 to db: 'default' user: 'root' host: '10.0.0.18' (Got timeout reading communication packets)

This would explain why the client reports a broken connection, **but** this error occurs 10-15 minutes before the client reports the "MySQL server has gone away" error. In the meantime, the client is happily running insert statements without an issue. But as soon the client runs a select statement, the statement fails practically immediately.

I have already checked for these possible causes:

1. The server was running all the time
2. **wait_timeout** is set to 8 hours, which is way longer than the time the transaction needs to fail
3. **max_allowed_packet** is set to 512M which should be more than enough since the query is a very short select statement
4. The server does not run out of memory

I'm pretty sure the issue must be related  to the "Got timeout reading communication packets" error from the MariaDB log. But I cannot wrap my head around why the client still can write data. And why this timeout occurs in the first place, since the **wait_timeout** is super high.

Some system information:

- I'm running on MariaDB 10.5.1
- The client uses python 3.6 and mysqlclient, which uses libmysql, is used for the database connection

I hope maybe some of you have an idea what I should look for, because this is really driving me nuts.

Comment: Look for any errors in the [error_log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log.html), just before the server goes down.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet is set to 512M`  probably way to high, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: If problems remain, maybe debug your python code? And try the cause of this.

Comment: EXTRA  (worth reading): [B.3.2.7 MySQL server has gone away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html)